# None of the clients of LogMeIn Hamachi mesh-network are reachable

Tags: windows-7, vpn, firewall, routing, hamachi

For some reason my Hamachi network stopped working. Here is what I have

- Version of the Hamachi client is 2.1.0.122
- It's "Mesh" network.
- I have 7 clients, 3 of them are online right now.
- All clients are Windows 7 Ultimate machines. Some are 64bit and others are 32bit Windows.
- Firewall is disabled on all clients.
- Hamachi client shows those who are online.
- I can chat with all clients using Hamachi-chat.

None of the clients of LogMeIn Hamachi mesh-network are reachable from each other - ICMP (ping) and TCP/IP don't work. I can ping myself using Hamachi IP address.

Just to localize the issue I connected two machines to same wifi router. Machines can access each other through IPs allocated by my router but can't access each other via Hamachi.

It worked before! I don't even know what changed :(

Any ideas what I can do, how to diagnose ?

Thanks a lot in advance!

**Update**
tracert gives following output:

```
C:\...le\AppData\Local\LogMeIn Hamachi>tracert 5.215.22.179

Tracing route to 5.215.22.179 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1     1 ms     1 ms     2 ms  expert [192.168.1.1]
  2    44 ms    27 ms    31 ms  76.102.224.1
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  6     *     ^C
```

Which is interesting. Why doesn't it go to its subnetwork? Who is supposed to set route for Hamachi network? Its client?

**Update2**

I'm sorry for false alarm. My routing table was messed up. It was caused by our corporate VPN client.

To fix the problem I had to:

- Disconnect from work VPN.
- Restart Hamachi windows service.
- Connect to work VPN again.

Comment: Please post your solution in a separate answer.

Comment: Can't do it now. My reputation is too low on this sub-site.